# Typo3 [globalVar = TSFE:id=6] - inheritance

Tags: typo3, typoscript, inheritance

I have a typo3 site and i wanna add a seperated css for one menu point with the subsite.

To the typoscript i added:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id=6]
  page.headerData.10 = TEXT
  page.headerData.10.value (
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileadmin/templates/blau.css"        media="all" />
)
[global]
```

So far it works for the page with the id 6. How can i write the script that it inherits the values for the sub sites of the page with the id 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this condition instead

```
[PIDinRootline = 6]
   page.headerData.10 = TEXT
   page.headerData.10.value (
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileadmin/templates/blau.css" media="all" />
   )
[GLOBAL]
```

You will find documentation on condition (here PIDinRootline) in the [TSref](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-pidinrootline)

Comment: Please, use code formatting and provide exact solution to the user's problem, not just copy/paste of text from a reference. Otherwise +1 for a good answer.

Comment: Sorry and thanks to point it out. It was my first post. I edited my post in this way.